# Cannot decipher symbols and question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Rasta calls a number like a Tavas if and only if $1 ≤ a ≤ n$ and the sum of all primes (like $p$) that $p | a$ is exactly equal to $k$.

He asks you to find the number of Tavases.

Given example

$n=20 k=7$

The only Tavases are $7$, $10$ and $20$.

what does $p | a$ mean? and how did it work out $7$, $10$ and $20$

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/rasta-and-tavas/

Comment: I think it means that $p$ divides $a.$

Comment: You're new here, so you don't yet know... but titles should refer to the specific topic under consideration.  Titles such as "I can't solve this, please help," or "I don't know what to do here," or your title, are vacuous.  Please look through this site to see proper style, and then rewrite yours.

Comment: This is poorly written.  I think you are meant to assume that $n,k$ are given.  If, for instance, we are told that $n=20,k=7$ then it is clear that $7,10,20$ are the only cases.  $7$ because $7=7$ while $10$ and $20$ because $2+5=7$.

Comment: Guys I know it's poorly written it makes no sense but I added link.

Comment: Ok, but I think it is clear what is meant.  Say you specify $n=40, k=9$.  Then we should only look at natural numbers $≤40$.  For each such number, say $35$, we list its prime divisors, $5,7$ in this case, and we add them, getting $12$ in this case.  If $12=k$, which it does not, we have a winner.  For this example, we see that $35$ is not a winner.  By contrast, $28$ is a winner since its prime divisors are $2,7$ and those sum to $9$.  You should easily be able to confirm that the only winners with $n=40, k=9$ are $14$ and $28$.

Comment: so  "sum of all primes (like p) that p | a is exactly equal to k" means the sum of all prime divisors of a must equal k. perfect lulu. That makes sense.

Comment: A huge problem I had reading you question was I read "a" as though it were the wod "a" as in "a rabbit" or "a bird".  I see by the link it is supposed to be a variable for a number called $a$.  Second problem was what does "like" mean and my grandmother would have a fit that the proper english grammer is "such as" not "like".  So I see now that the question is more like:  Rasta defines a number, such as $a$, to be "Tavas" for a specific $n$ and $k$, if $1\le a \le n$ then if the sum of all the primes, $p$, that divide $a$ evenly, add up to exactly k".

Comment: So one way to solve this is to find all the primes that add to $7$. $7=7$ and $2+5=7$ and that's it.  So the Tavases are the numbers that have only $7$ as a prime divisor or have $2$ and $5$ as prime divisors.  For $a \le 20$ those are $7$ and $10$ and $20$. If $n=100$ we'd have $7,49$.  And $10,20,40,50,80,100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the question:

For any natural number $m$ we define $F(m)$ to be the sum of the distinct prime divisors of $m$.  Thus $F(p)=p$ if $p$ is prime.  Indeed, $F(p^r)=p$ if $p$ is prime.  $F(20)=7$ since the prime divisors of $20$ are $2,5$ and $2+5=7$ and so on.

Given $n, k$ the questions asks us to find all natural numbers $m$ such that $$m≤n\quad \&\quad F(m)=k$$

For reasonably sized $n,k$ this should be a fairly easy computation.